# SSL certificate configuration

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have successfully added SSL certificate to my url. now url is "https://puinex5xgm-l1". Its working fine on browser. but whenever I try to add port to this ulr "https://puinex5xgm-l1:90/" its giving me "**SSL connection error ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR**". My apache server is running on port 90.

While creating certificate I have used domain name as "puinex5xgm-l1".

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR is not related to the certificate. My guess is that you don't have https on port 90 enabled but instead plain http, which then will cause such an error.

Comment: Below are the changes that I have made in httpd.conf file.
Listen 90
<VirtualHost *:90>
ServerName puinex5xgm-l1:90
//Some proxy call *******
<VirtualHost *:90>.
Please correct me if I am doing wrong.

Comment: @user2042462: From only these information it is not really visible what's going on but if there is only a proxy call there then you don't have https configured for port 90. But for details on the server config you better ask at serverfault.com, although I recommend you to include way more of the config than you did here.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

I have made changes in "httpd-ssl.conf" file. Here, I have used "VirtualHost *default*:90" instead of "VirtualHost *default*:443".

Now Apache server listening my port.

Its working fine now.